# Flow Type aliases on React stateless components

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I'm trying to implement flow into my React application. So far it worked fine, but i'm having trouble with a default value.

The function header is:

```
const FormControls = ({ form, controls = null, labels = {} }: { form: any, controls: ?TFormControls, labels?: TFormControlLabels}) => (
```

The type alias for TFormControls is:

```
type TFormControls = {
  onSubmit?: boolean,
  onReset?: boolean,
  onClear?: boolean
}
```

I would expect, since I put a maybe operator in there `controls: ?TFormControls`, that it would either be my type-alias or null/undefined, but flow tells me:

```
src/components/forms/FormControls.jsx:35
 35: const FormControls = ({ form, controls = null, labels = {} }: { form: any, controls: ?TFormControls, labels?: TFormControlLabels}) => (
                                   ^^^^^^^^ null. This type is incompatible with
 35: const FormControls = ({ form, controls = null, labels = {} }: { form: any, controls: ?TFormControls, labels?: TFormControlLabels}) => (
                                   ^^^^^^^^ object type

src/components/forms/FormControls.jsx:35
 35: const FormControls = ({ form, controls = null, labels = {} }: { form: any, controls: ?TFormControls, labels?: TFormControlLabels}) => (
                                   ^^^^^^^^ object type. This type is incompatible with
 35: const FormControls = ({ form, controls = null, labels = {} }: { form: any, controls: ?TFormControls, labels?: TFormControlLabels}) => (
                                   ^^^^^^^^ null
```

Any pointers would be most welcome!

Edit: As requested, the full function with error as an [example](https://flowtype.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAFQDFoQBhCAOxhwBsBnOALxwA3qThwOAZQCuAIxDAYAfgBccWRAjdU7ADRiJ7ZLyTK1GrTv3iOLbSiir1m++1IBfCtVqNmbTjwAMiiySHyCIgZScgpmcLxcwOwA5taGxqZOCVBJqVHsdqiOatm5HuRoHAnxVNr8QsJwSFA4UGr4+Lrq0jAwHADiONJg7fiepJXs1UxQrBxcWvVwABSNmMxdkwvhQuzS3Nxd3CFhS8LucO5qa8xqAPKyAFZIGJvzPLxqSr6z-tu8RxOfCcPzmAS0wVCfHcAEo1Mh0DAAHQAUW0ICQnAAPAAqAB8ggJywMWIAJsAAG54gziLGyKBwAD01PEtLALNZtOANUo2gEwgSvKQvCRzVa7g5nPEwnWs1FLWgnilcCxjOAkpVjPZNJV9KZ1J1ZMpPL5AtqwqRsh6fXYgwgwwlOulywAhFsPnAAD6euDuxZIjgZGAwuAAMlDTpV5IpkZsBW4wDQAGt+bKQAGjMLTErlXAqDQBAAiK29DiF2NwY5Q-lV05IogmeDeghBsaR5njZXCV1+8LN3si2z2KAh8ORo0x3OGOyJlMy5gZwoOHPK-NIIslm3lqe17g1oEitDDr0+-BLqBt5Ud8hdnvvRYn333vgZmTyRSjiPKicVoez1MLtE74wCuUprkWvAxIo265mAOQgA4lD8lw0hIKBnK7vuUIipBwGPvgb6xJeUrXpyqrRhy5GUtSMJAA)

Comment: Can you post a complete example? It would make it easier for the people who are trying to help you. You can even just post a link to what you come up with in http://flowtype.org/try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [defaultProps class property](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops).

In particular, here is how you might define your prop parameters:

```
type FormControlsPropsType = {
  form: Object,
  controls: TFormControls,
  labels: TFormControlLabels
};

const FormControls = ({
  form,
  controls,
  labels
} : FormControlsPropsType): React.Element<*> => (
  // ...etc
);
```

And here is how you might define defaultProps:

```
FormControls.defaultProps = {
  controls: null,
  labels: {},
}
```

Finally, because you are defining defaults there is no reason to define the PropsType with optional parameters. You'll see I removed the `?`'s.

By setting defaults in the parameter definitions, you may have been running into conflicts with [React$Element](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.40.0/lib/react.js#L121) internals.

Here is a [working FlowType example](https://flowtype.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAFQDFoQBhCAOxhwBsBnOALxwA3qThwOAZQCuAIxDAYAfgBccWRAjdU7ADRiJ7ZLyTK1GrTv3iOLbSiir1m++1IBfCtVqNmbTjwAMiiySHyCIgZScgpmcLxcwOwA5taGxqZOCVBJqVHsdqiOatm5HuRoHAnxVNr8QsJwSFA4UGr4+Lrq0jAwHADiONJg7fiepJXs1UxQrBxcWvVwABSNmMxdkwt8XdwhYfzuamvMagDysgBWSBib8zy8ar6z-tu8u-t8TzNzAVrBoT47gAlGpkOgYAA6ACi2hASE4AB4AFQAPkE6OWBkRABNgAA3VEGcSI2RQOAAeiJ4hJYGpNJJwBqlG0AmECRZSF4kOarXc9IZ4mE61mPJa0E8grgiIpwAF0opdOJ0rJlKJytxBOZrPZtS5kNkPT67EGEGG-OVQuWAEItg84AAfB1wO2LSEcDIwYFwABkPst0rx+IDNgK3GAaAA1myRSB3UYuaZJVK4FQaAIAESG3ocDMhuB7QFswsHSFEEzwJ0ET1jANU8ZS4Q213hKst7m2exQb1+gOa4Mpwx2CPR4XMeOFBzJqVppCZ7PGvODkvcYufbloLuO534SdQWtS+vkRvN+6Lbcus98eMyeSKHv+qX9-Odkcx8fRO8waeC2eZ3gxIoS4pmAOQgA4lBslw0hID+DIrmugLcgBX4Xvgt6xAegpHgyMpBvSeEEkSwIANzkD8rwPJCOJIJgKDSNwMAAAo4GASyiOI7ZqOwDHcGkK6PCI7j6O4QA).